# How to increment a variable with some values and reorder the result

Tags: php, increment

I wanted to increment this variable with these values:

```
$Variable = "AAAA1 VALUE1; \
             BBBB1 VALUE1; \
             CCCC1 VALUE1";
```

So i made this simple code:

```
for($i=1; $i<3; $i++) {
$Variable = "AAAA$i VALUE$i; \
             BBBB$i VALUE$i; \
             CCCC$i VALUE$i";
}
```

And i got this 2 output results:

> AAAA1 VALUE1 
>  BBBB1 VALUE1 
> CCCC1 VALUE1 
>  AAAA2 VALUE2 
>   BBBB2 VALUE2 
> CCCC2 VALUE2

But what i want, is to get one full result like that:

> AAAA1 VALUE1 
>  AAAA2 VALUE2 
>  BBBB1 VALUE1 
> BBBB2 VALUE2
> CCCC1 VALUE1
> CCCC2 VALUE2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the string an array and loop each item one by one and build the string inside a for loop similar yours.

```
$Variable = "AAAA VALUE
BBBB VALUE
CCCC VALUE";
$startval = 1;
$endval = 5;

$var = explode("\n", $Variable);

$str = "";
foreach($var as $v){
    $temp = explode(" " , $v);
    //Loop from startval to endval and build your string
    for($i=$startval; $i<=$endval; $i++){
        $str .= $temp[0] .$i . " " . $temp[1] .$i. "\n";
    }
    $str .= "\n"; // add new line
}

echo $str;
```

Output:

```
AAAA1 VALUE1
AAAA2 VALUE2
AAAA3 VALUE3
AAAA4 VALUE4
AAAA5 VALUE5

BBBB1 VALUE1
BBBB2 VALUE2
BBBB3 VALUE3
BBBB4 VALUE4
BBBB5 VALUE5

CCCC1 VALUE1
CCCC2 VALUE2
CCCC3 VALUE3
CCCC4 VALUE4
CCCC5 VALUE5
```

https://3v4l.org/OPA8K

Answer (score 3):

in blow code:

```
"AAAA$i VALUE$i;  
 BBBB$i VALUE$i;  
 CCCC$i VALUE$i";
```

you want iterate in each row!

`$variable = explode("\n",$Variable);`

now `$variable` is iterable , or use array:

```
$variable=[
             "AAAA%input1% VALUE%input1%;",
             "BBBB%input1% VALUE%input1%;",
             "CCCC%input1% VALUE%input1%;",
];

$final_string="";
foreach($variable as $var){

    for($i=1; $i<3; $i++) {
        $final_string. = str_replace("%input1%",$i,$var) ."\n";
    }

}

echo $final_string;
```